# Emit ASM from Cranelift

Tags: rust, compiler-construction

Is there the possibility to emit ASM when compiling something using Cranelift? By "ASM" I mean the assembler text-representation, in e.g. Intel-Syntax or similar

Now I was planing on implementing this myself using a dissasembler-library like [Capstone](https://docs.rs/capstone/latest/capstone/) or [Iced](https://github.com/icedland/iced), but then I found [`Context::set_disasm(bool)`](https://docs.rs/cranelift-codegen/latest/cranelift_codegen/struct.Context.html#method.set_disasm) which apparently does exactly what I need. The problem is I'm unable to find where to extract this assembler-code from. There's no function like `get_disasm` as far as I looked.

If it's relevant, I'm building both a JIT and an AOT compiler and I want the dissasembler to work when using either.

Can one help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Retrieve [the `disasm` field](https://docs.rs/cranelift-codegen/0.92.0/src/cranelift_codegen/machinst/mod.rs.html#289-290) of `CompiledCode`. It is in `CompiledCodeBase`, so it is not documented, unfortunately.